# Paypal recurring deposit from one user to another

Tags: php, yii, paypal, frameworks, paypal-sandbox

I have done a project in YII. 
Consider there are two accounts parent and child. Parent has to deposit or transfer funds for the child.
I have successfully integrated paypal recurring deposit for the parent account. 
Are there any options in paypal or in the code level, that the recurring amount could be deposited directly to the child of a parent account?
**Note:** child won't have a paypal account.

Comment: You know that PayPal already offers youth accounts with this functionality, right?

Comment: Ya right, its a simple fund transfer to the child account from a parent account. But my question, is there any possibilities to implement recurring deposit directly to a child account(in my site) from a parent account using the paypal recurring deposit feature? (where parent have a paypal account and child wont be having a paypal youth account).